# How does a react app can be set up on server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, server

I'm trying to understand what needs to be done to put my react app online.

Until now, I launched it on my mac using `npm start`, and accessing `localhost:3000` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

So I currently have bought a small server, installed everything (last version of `node` and `npm`, git and other necessary things), cloned my repo, and installed all dependencies.

When I do `npm start` on the server, it says it's available on port 3000. But when I go in my server's ip with the following `:3000`, it times out.

I don't really understand what need to be done to do this, I found some things about configuring apache on the server, others about using `pm2` so have a node script running even after leaving the terminal, but that would be my next step I guess.. And other about configuring things with express (but do I need `node`+ `express` here ? As it's a simple front end react page ?).

Comment: Port 3000 isn't published by default - you will need something like an NGINX proxy to accept requests on port 80 or 443 and route them to your app

Comment: If you used ``create-react-app``, may you need to add ``proxy`` in your ``package.json``to proxy API request on your server.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [webpack devserver](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/), use it for development only

> The tools in this guide are only meant for development, please avoid using them in production!

back to your question, there is [a difference between binding to `127.0.0.1` or binding to `0.0.0.0`](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0)

try changing the [devserver to listen to `0.0.0.0`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost)

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
};
```

Usage via the CLI

```sh
webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0
```

also note, that you will need to allow ingress rules (incoming connections). that is, allow a request from the internet to reach your server

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of configurations you will have to do when you deploy your application on a server. Building the app, Nginx, pm2 and even ssl certification. This video is 20min and has all you need. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oykl1Ih9pMg&t=1s

Comment: Thx for the link I think it will be usefull afterwards but I did all the things he did before 7min30, that's where i'm stuck (It seems I can't access my server's IP:3000)

Comment: I found the place to open port 3000. So now I have access to it. Now I need to understand how to launch a `create-react-app` on the server (but for long term). The youtube link you gave talk about node.js files with pm2.

Comment: (the base file of my app is `public/index.html`, and not a `.js` file)

Comment: You need an `express` server to serve that public/index.html

Comment: Do i need `pm2` also ?

Comment: You need to build your react app. And you already found the entery point html `index.html`. So now you must create an express server to serve  that index.html. Express server will serve it and pm2 will start your app, instead of npm you will start and run your app with pm2. But first you need to code an express server and  configure it to serve your index.html to client.

Comment: All right thanks, i'm going to get documented about `express` & `pm2` then :)

Comment: good luck with it. I think you should specificly look for `serving create-react-app with express`